# Exact match formula for Multiple select field when value has comma

Tags: airtable

I need a formula to check if there is exact matching for multiple select field when values can have comma.
Here is a sample multiple select I can have:

- a
- b
- c
- a,b

I need to check if users selection is exactly 'c' and 'a,b'.
All solutions I found (like using FIND) are not working with comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer can be found in [airtable community](https://community.airtable.com/t5/formulas/exact-match-formula-for-multiple-select-field-when-value-has/m-p/164498/highlight/true#M19529).

Here is filter:

```html
IF(
  AND(
    REGEX_MATCH("##"&REGEX_REPLACE({select},", ","##")&"##","##c##"),
    REGEX_MATCH("##"&REGEX_REPLACE({select},", ","##")&"##",'##"a,b"##'),
    LEN({select})=LEN('c, "a,b"')
  )
  ,1
)
```